# what is alternative of R::$f->now() in redbean 4.X

Tags: redbean

in `redbean` v.3.x there is option to select date from db like [R::$f->now()](http://www.redbeanphp.com/manual3_0/index.php?p=/manual3_0/mixing_sql_and_php)   what is alternative of this in `redbean` v.4.x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `R::getCell('SELECT now()');` to run any sql commands, to get current time you just need to call `R::isoDate();` or `R::isoDateTime();`